# How to create a Multi-Level Combobox in YII

Tags: php, yii, combobox

Table categories:

```
   id  
   name 
   parent_id
```

values

```
   1 - Main Category  - 0,
   2 - Main Category1 - 1,
   3 - Main category2 - 1,
   4 - Subcategory 1  - 2,
   5 - Subcategory 2  - 2
   6 - Main category3 - 1
```

Combobox Like this

```
Main Category 
     --> Main Category 1
     -------->SubCategory 1
     -------->SubCategory 2
     --> Main Category 2
     --> Main Category 3
```

Help me guys....thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have a nested array with your values to display:

```
        foreach ($mainarray as $category => $level1elements) {
        echo CHtml::openTag('optgroup', array('label'=>CHtml::encode($category)));
        foreach ($level1elements as $value => $name) 
            echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
        echo CHtml::closeTag('optgroup');
    }
```

something like this should fit your needs.
[CHtml::listData](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail) should be able to do it easily, but so far I didn't manage to make it work as I would.